# jump to next paragraph autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to tab from the keybaord to the next paragraph within the Matlab Editor. This is not possible within the Matlab Editor, so I am looking for an Autohotkeyscript that would do that. For example, consider two blocks below:

Aaaa;
aaaa;

Bbbb;
bbbb;

I would like to be able to press the keyboard shortcut CTRL+Down and CTRL+Up to tab between curseor position on in Aaaa; and Bbbb;

This in fact standard in most editors like UltraEdit etc. but not in the Matlab Editor. is there a simple way to implement this with an autohotkey script.

thanks

Comment: How do you perform the required action right now? (through the keyboard, not by using your mouse). Do you want to jump to the next/previous line and stay at the same cursor position, or do you want to jump to the next/previous line and have the cursor placed at the beginning of a line or word?